# require in Sapper preload function

Tags: javascript, svelte, sapper

I am trying to parse some markdown before a page loads, so I have the following code:

```
<script context="module">
    var markdown = require( "markdown" ).markdown;

    export async function preload(page, session) {
        var someMakrdown = '# Title'
        var html = markdown.toHTML(someMakrdown)
        return {post : html}
    }
</script>
```

This fails with a 500 and the message:  `require is not defined`

I have also tried using import in the following way:

```
<script context="module">
    import {markdown} from 'markdown';

    export async function preload(page, session) {
        var someMakrdown = '# Title'
        var html = markdown.toHTML(someMakrdown)
        return {post : html}
    }
</script>
```

This also fails with a 500 and the message `Error resolving module specifier: util`

I have got this to work by moving the code into a `[slug].json.js` file and calling that from within the preload, but is there a better way to do this?

One of the things that I've enjoyed so far about Svelte is keeping the HTML, CSS and JS together for each component.  It just doesn't feel right that I need to call a seperate JS file to create JSON that can then be used.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the `markdown` module imports `util`, making it unsuitable for client-side use. Since `preload` functions run both server-side and client-side, that's no good. My suggestion would be to use a different library instead (I can recommend [marked](https://www.npmjs.com/package/marked)) and/or raise an issue on the `markdown` bug tracker.

Comment: I am hitting this same issue when using the npm faunadb module, also with sapper. The code works in React application. Is there another work around for situations like these, or could it be a situation with rollup or webpack not adding it?

example I see in console.
'util' is imported by node_modules/faunadb/src/values.js, but could not be resolved – treating it as an external dependency

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone needs a complete answer, here's how it looks like using `marked`, as proposed by Rich.

```
<script context="module">
    import marked from 'marked';
    let elem = '';
    export function preload({ params, query }) {
        elem = marked('# Marked in the server or/and browser');
    }
</script>

<div>{@html elem}</div>
```

It'll run in the server and then, for subsequent navigation, in the browser.

Comment: Please don't do this! Your `preload` function should be pure. There's no benefit to doing the markdown conversion there rather than in the template itself (i.e. `{@html marked(markdown)}`)